# Pygame, if key pressed and then released action

Tags: python, pygame

I am experimenting with physics for a game and wanted to try how you can speed up.

My current code is this

```
    def left(self):
        self.x -= 1 * self.xvelocity
        if not self.xvelocity == 10:
            self.xvelocity += 1

    def right(self):
        self.x += 1 * self.xvelocity
        if not self.xvelocity == 10:
            self.xvelocity += 1

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.left()

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.right()
```

I am wanting to reset xvelocity back to 0 if the right or left key got released. At the moment this is not happening so if you move right and speed up, and then move left you still have the same velocity.

I tried to fix it by adding this:

```
    def left(self, *args):
        if args:
            self.x -= 1 * self.xvelocity
            if not self.xvelocity == 10:
                self.xvelocity += 1
        else:
            self.xvelocity = 0

    def right(self, *args):
        if args:
            self.x += 1 * self.xvelocity
            if not self.xvelocity == 10:
                self.xvelocity += 1
        else:
            self.xvelocity = 0
```

But am not able to get the effect of having to speed up again if you change direction. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try breaking down your left/right inputs as follows:

```
1) left. Increase velocity to left till max 
2) right. increase velocity to right till max 
3) L+R. Invalid 
4) No input. Velocity resets to zero 
5) L->R/R->L. left velocity resets to zero and now increases in right direction. vice-versa
```

Looking at your initial code, you made the mistake of flipping the signs without zeroing your speed. Your 'velocity' variable is actually speed. and the sign you used on the change to self.x represent your direction. I have proposed a slightly diffrent approach that ensures direction is included in your velocity. -ve to the left and +ve to the right. Do bear in mind you probably need to create cases for No input and L+R.

```
def left(self):
    if self.xvelocity>0: #If heading to the right, reset velocity to 0
        self.xvelocity = 0
    else: #We were not heading to the right so begin left ward velocity
        self.xvelocity -=1
    self.x += 1*max(-10,self.xvelocity) #another way to set limit on negative velocity

def right(self): # simply a reflect of the above
    if self.xvelocity<0:
        self.xvelocity = 0
    else:
        self.xvelocity +=1
    self.x += 1*min(10,self.xvelocity)
```